# Swift 3 Navigation Bar Item Scrolling

Tags: scroll, swift3, uinavigationbar, xcode8

Is it possible to have the items in a navigation bar be scrollable?  In order words, if I have 5+ items in the navigation bar, I want to be able to scroll through them horizontally.  I have seen it with custom buttons and custom navigation bars, but I want to know if it can be done with View Controller with an embedded Navigation Controller.

Comment: No that's not a default behavior that Apple provides. You need a custom navigation bar.

Comment: Add a screenshot of your current attempt, please. Do you want the scrolling to be paged?

Comment: @DanielLegler I know you can customize certain aspects of the stock Apple navigation bar.  Can you not have this particular feature with it?